# Remove duplicate from a list of type class

Tags: c#, list, class, duplicates

I have a class with a following properties

`id` (type: unique `long`), `name` (type: `string`), version major (`VM`) (type:`long`), version minor (`Vm`) (type: `long`)

I create a list of this class and the list looks as follows

```
ID    Name     VM    Vm
1     ssim     2     1
2     SSim     3     1
3     Counter  5     1
4     Counter  6     2
5     Counter  6     5
```

I would like to remove duplicates from the list based on Version Major and then version minor. The final list should look as follows

```
ID    Name     VM    Vm
2     SSim     3     1
5     Counter  6     5
```

Comment: Should the order of the items be preserved?

Comment: Also, are you using a list or hashtable? They aren't the same thing so you shouldn't need/use both tags.

Comment: From your example of final list it looks like you only want to retain names based on max VersionMajor and VersionMinor, not to remove duplicates.

Comment: In terms of order it doesn't matter but it will be good if they are alphabatical.

Comment: Yes my final list will retain names based on max VersionMajr and VersionMinor.

Comment: Alphabetical? So you want to de-dupe **and** sort the list?

Comment: @Abe There are 5 answers to your question. Does one of them solve your problem? If so, mark one of them as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say your class is `ProgramEntry`:

```
public class ProgramEntry {

    public long Id;
    public string Name;
    public long VM;
    public long Vm;

    public ProgramEntry (long id, string name, long vM, long vm) {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        VM = vM;
        Vm = vm;
    }

    public override string ToString () {
        return this.Id+":"+this.Name+"("+this.VM+"."+this.Vm+")";
    }

}
```

(yes, using public fields is not good practice, but it simply a *quick-and-dirty* solution)

Now you can order them by version (first major, then minor):

```
List<ProgramEntry> programs = new List<ProgramEntry>();
//fill list with programs
var order = programs.OrderBy(x => -x.VM).ThenBy(x => -x.Vm);
```

This results in a `IEnumerable<ProgramEntry>` ordered with largest major first, and in case of equivalent major, largest minor first.

Next you can use [this duplicate filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/489421/67579), to filter out elements with the same `Name`:

```
List<ProgramEntry> result = order.DistinctBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

The `DistinctBy` is by the way part of the [*MoreLINQ*](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ) library. Or you can implement it yourself using an *extension class*:

```
public static class Foo {

    public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>
        (this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector) {
        HashSet<TKey> seenKeys = new HashSet<TKey>();
        foreach (TSource element in source) {
            if (seenKeys.Add(keySelector(element))) {
                yield return element;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Demo** (using the `csharp` interactive shell):

```
$ csharp
Mono C# Shell, type "help;" for help

Enter statements below.
csharp> public class ProgramEntry {
      >  
      >     public long Id;
      >     public string Name;
      >     public long VM;
      >     public long Vm;
      >  
      >     public ProgramEntry (long id, string name, long vM, long vm) {
      >         Id = id;
      >         Name = name;
      >         VM = vM;
      >         Vm = vm;
      >     }
      >  
      >     public override string ToString () {
      >         return this.Id+":"+this.Name+"("+this.VM+"."+this.Vm+")";
      >     }
      >  
      > }
csharp> List<ProgramEntry> programs = new List<ProgramEntry>();
csharp> programs.Add(new ProgramEntry(1,"ssim",2,1));
csharp> programs.Add(new ProgramEntry(2,"ssim",3,1)); 
csharp> programs.Add(new ProgramEntry(3,"Counter",5,1));
csharp> programs.Add(new ProgramEntry(4,"Counter",6,2)); 
csharp> programs.Add(new ProgramEntry(5,"Counter",6,5)); 
csharp> programs
{ 1:ssim(2.1), 2:ssim(3.1), 3:Counter(5.1), 4:Counter(6.2), 5:Counter(6.5) }
csharp> var order = programs.OrderBy(x => -x.VM).ThenBy(x => -x.Vm);
csharp> order
{ 5:Counter(6.5), 4:Counter(6.2), 3:Counter(5.1), 2:ssim(3.1), 1:ssim(2.1) }
csharp> List<ProgramEntry> result = order.DistinctBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
csharp> result
{ 5:Counter(6.5), 2:ssim(3.1) }
```

Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: I do not have the option distincyBy.

Comment: @Abe: as specified in the answer, it is part of the [*MoreLINQ*](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ) library. But you can implement it yourself using an extension method (see updated answer).

Comment: Thank you simple question. How do i call that method Foo.DistinctBy( )  I am not sure what the paramteres will be.  I am not very familiar with linq.

Comment: @Abe: the `this` in the parameters means it is an *extension method*. This means that if you call it as `a.DistinctBy(b)`, it is translated internally to `Foo.DistinctBy(a,b)`.

Comment: Thank you. As per your example what is 'a' and what is 'b'?

Comment: I got it . will test and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, I think:

```
public class Product
{
    public Product(long id, string name, int major, int minor)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Major = major;
        this.Minor = minor;
    }

    public long Id { get; set; }

    public int Major { get; set; }

    public int Minor { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

private static void Main()
{
    IEnumerable<Product> products = new List<Product>
                                    {
                                        new Product(1, "ssim", 2, 1),
                                        new Product(2, "SSim", 3, 1),
                                        new Product(3, "Counter", 5, 1),
                                        new Product(4, "Counter", 6, 2),
                                        new Product(5, "Counter", 6, 5)
                                    };

    IEnumerable<Product> distinctProducts =
        (from x in products group x by x.Name.ToLower() into g select g.OrderByDescending(y => y.Major).ThenByDescending(y => y.Minor).First()).OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So you want the maximum version of each name.

You can do it with linq like this:

```
void Main()
{
    var versions = new List<Version>
    {
     new Version(1,2, "a"),
     new Version(1,3, "a"),
     new Version(1,3, "b"),
     new Version(1,4, "b"),
     new Version(1,1, "b"),
     new Version(2,3, "c")
    };

    var distinctVersions = versions
    .GroupBy(g => g.name.ToLowerInvariant())
    .Select(g => g.ToList().OrderBy(x => x.major).ThenBy(x => x.minor).Last())
    .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Great LINQ demonstration ;) Maybe you could just add `.ToLower()`, when grouping by name to make grouping case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose this class resembles your data:

```
public class VerX
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int VerMajor { get; set; }
    public int VerMinor { get; set; }
}
```

For your sample, this is how this data is filled:

```
var list = new List<VerX>
{
    new VerX { ID = 1, Name = "ssim", VerMajor = 2, VerMinor = 1 },
    new VerX { ID = 2, Name = "SSim", VerMajor = 3, VerMinor = 1 },
    new VerX { ID = 3, Name = "Counter", VerMajor = 5, VerMinor = 1 },
    new VerX { ID = 4, Name = "Counter", VerMajor = 6, VerMinor = 2 },
    new VerX { ID = 5, Name = "Counter", VerMajor = 6, VerMinor = 5 },
};
```

Now, lets create a loop that would provide you with the desired result:

```
// First create new list that would hold the results
var listNew = new List<VerX>();

// Select distinct names from data (using ToLower, so casing does not matter)
var names = list.Select(t => t.Name.ToLower()).Distinct().ToList();

// Loop through each of distinct name
foreach (var name in names)
{
    // With LINQ, select item whose name matches and sort list by VerMajor
    // descending and VerMinor descending and take first item.
    var item = list.Where(t => t.Name.Equals(name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                   .OrderByDescending(t => t.VerMajor)
                   .ThenByDescending(t => t.VerMinor)
                   .FirstOrDefault();

    // If item not found (although it should be found!), continue the loop
    if (item == null)
        continue;

    // Add item to new list
    listNew.Add(item);
}

// At the end of the loop, the listNew contains items as in your proposed result.
```

The same foreach loop can be obtained by more complex LINQ query:

```
// Select distinct names as in first case
var names = list.Select(t => t.Name.ToLower()).Distinct().ToList();

// Construct listNew from names based on same algorithm as before, but using LINQ this time.
var listNew = names
    .Select(name => list.Where(t => t.Name.Equals(name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                        .OrderByDescending(t => t.VerMajor)
                        .ThenByDescending(t => t.VerMinor)
                        .FirstOrDefault())
    .Where(item => item != null)
    .ToList();

 // Here, listNew contains your desired result.
```

Based on your desired result, this provides you with results grouped by name, based on max VerMajor and max VerMinor.

Comment: We have to sort it by version major and version minor first.  Then delete the distinct names otherwise i might lose data if the the version is greater but name is duplicate. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I don't understand quite exactly. From your post is seems you would like to keep names (and other data, e.g. ID) with highest version (VerMajor, VerMinor). That means first grouping by name and then keeping only highest version.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you ask could be easily done with this code:

```
var groupsByName = myItems.GroupBy(x => x.Name.ToLower());

var distinctItems = groupsByName.Select(x => x.ToList()
                                .OrderByDescending(y => y.VM)
                                .ThenByDescending(z => z.Vm).First())
                                .OrderBy(k => k.Name).ToList();
```